# How to get in Android Usb Host what Usb Device responses after Host sends command?

Tags: android, android-usb, usb-hostcontroller

Following [the simple tutorial](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/host.html) I'm able to connect to device (usb optical mouse with ADNS-5000 chip inside) and make a [bulkTransfer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/usb/UsbDeviceConnection.html#bulkTransfer%28android.hardware.usb.UsbEndpoint,%20byte[],%20int,%20int%29).

```
UsbInterface intf = device.getInterface(0);
UsbEndpoint endpoint = intf.getEndpoint(0);
UsbDeviceConnection connection = manager.openDevice(device);
connection.claimInterface(intf, forceClaim);
connection.bulkTransfer(endpoint, bytes, bytes.length, TIMEOUT); //do in another thread
```

ADNS-5000 spec (can be googled out) defines some set of "USB Commands" among which there is for example:

> Mnemonic: Get_Status_Device
>
> Command: 80 00 00 00 00 00 02 00
>
> Notes: Normally returns 00 00, Self powered 00 00, Remote wakeup 02 00

So I understand it like: when I write data:

```
private byte[] bytes = {(byte) 0x80, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x02, 0x00};
```

to the device I should get either `0x00, 0x00` or `0x00, 0x00` *(this is probably an error in spec as this byte sequence is defined as result for two different statuses)* or `0x20, 0x00` in return, **but I don't see any way the api returns anything, am I right?**

Answer (score 0):

I took a quick look on a ADNS-5000 specification. One thing is for sure, you have IN and OUT endpoint available.

> Get_Status_Endpt0 82 00 00 00 xx 00 02 00 OUT: xx=00, IN:
>   xx=80 Normally returns 00 00

**Which means that commands (there is no API) can return result.**

The only way that I can imagine would be to write command to OUT endpoint and read (by polling) the status (after command execution) from IN endpoint.

This is something that I've been using in a few projects and it is perfectly fine. I am not sure about ADNS-5000 since I haven't checked the USB protocol details.

Hope it helps.